# trying to parse weird formatted xml in php

Tags: php, xml, curl, parsing

I am trying to chop XML data into usable strings to reuse them later on in my script.

I am receiving the data via a Curl request and his goes great.
now chopping the data kills me..

this a part of the XML I am receiving (the whole data part is about 90 lines)

```
<professions>
    <skill key="IT Specialist" maxage="40" group="IT" worked="5"/>
    <skill key="Assistant" maxage="35" group="Office" worked="5"/>
</professions>
```

Now of course I could make a function filtering data etc, but I just feel there is a different way to get the job done.
The XML is loaded in a $var.

Any help getting this done better than reading the string etc etc would be helpfull.

Comment: @Fons - Can you stop reverting my edit?  My changes are making your XML actually show up.

Comment: Was trying to get it to show, thanks for you edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`xml_parse_into_struct()` is nice.

Comment: Looking into this right now, will keep you in the loop with the result.

Comment: Getting the Half the data in the array now, great!
Values are recorded, index not.
Will try to find a way around that. Thanks a lot!

Regards
Fons

Comment: Works like a charm! very fast as well.

Thanks a lot
Fons

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if I don't understand your problem correctly, but what's the problem with simply throwing the XML into [`SimpleXML`](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) which is by far the easiest to use PHP XML API and it also supports XPath for selective data extraction:

```
$data = simplexml_load_string($var);
echo $data->skill[0]['key']; // will print "IT Specialist"
foreach ($data->skill as $skill) {
    printf('%s in group %s with max. age %d and %d year(s) of experience', 
        $skill['key'], $skill['group'], $skill['maxage'], $skill['worked']) . "\n";
}
/*
 * this will print:
 * IT Specialist in group IT with max. age 40 and 5 year(s) of experience
 * Assistant in group Office with max. age 35 and 5 year(s) of experience
 */
$keys = $data->xpath('/professions/skill/@key');
foreach ($keys as $key) {
    echo $key . "\n";
}
/*
 * this will print:
 * IT Specialist
 * Assistant
 */
// and you can do a lot more...
```

I cannot think of any reason why one would bother with the weird data structure [`xml_parse_into_struct()`](http://de3.php.net/xml_parse_into_struct) creates (besides when writing some own XML parser-like functionality), when there are tools that handle the given problem much easier. But perhaps I misunderstood your question...